# Dual Boot problem

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows 7 install already an later on I installed Ubuntu but after installation and reboot it wasn't showing dual boot option.

I'm a totally new user can anyone guide me quickly on this.

Comment: I don get it, Is it ubuntu thats not booting or is it windows?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will probably fix it

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write to which system Your PC boots by default. If it is Ubuntu then Amith KK's answer will do. If it is Windows then run

```
msconfig
```

and find the option

```
 time limit
```

in BOOT tab and set it to 30 seconds.